# Exponentiate all elements of a list without alter the list

Tags: list, haskell, fold

The list is

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

and I want exponentiate each result. So, it would be:

> (2 ^ 3) ^ 4 = 4096

My solution is

- use foldl
- set manually the first element of the list as the base case
- set manually the base case as the first element of the list

The code is

```
foldl (^) 2 [1, 3, 4]
```

The trace is

> ((2 ^ 1) ^ 3) ^ 4 = 4096

Is there a solution without alter the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in case the list is guaranteed to have a *first* element, we can use [**`foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:foldl1) which uses the *first* element of the list as initial accumulator. So we can use:

```
foldl1 (^) [2, 3, 4]
```

This of course produces the same result:

```
Prelude> foldl1 (^) [2,3,4]
4096
```

Note that in case you use an *empty* list the above function will error. So you will need to handle that case - if that is a possibility - by some extra logic.

Comment: for this particular case, since `x ^ 1 = x`, you can guard against the empty list case with `\xs -> foldl1 (^) (xs ++ [1])`. Or, y'know, use `Maybe`.